# How plausible is it that every decohered entity has qualia, which merge into functional units?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, consciousness, qualia, functionalism, panpsychism

I only say decohered because the quantum realm doesn't seem to have the local reality to have locally functional qualia, but maybe it has more diffuse probabilistic qualia? Then again in our macro world, although we perceive separate units (individuals), and evolution works on that, in reality it's all flowing into each other.

Is quantum entanglement an example of consciousness at the quantum level?

By qualia I just mean phenomenal consciousness, phenomenality. But stripping away anything specific to the incredible evolved complexity of animal brains.

See Panpsychism.

Comment: "How plausible" on what basis beyond opinions? We do not even know what qualia are in people, and this goes several steps of speculation beyond that.

Comment: Well we know what people are - bits of Earth (mostly water) that grow functionally, with some macro electrochemical activity, and experience functional qualia.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [fallacy of division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_division)? Just because some composite (like humans) has a property (like having qualia) does not mean that its components (like chemicals) also have it. It is equally "plausible" that qualia are emergent on complexity of animal brains that you want to strip away and high level dynamic processes there. And this "plausibility" is just pointing fingers into the sky because we do not know enough even about the supposed prototype.

Comment: You seem to be giving a bland answer (that it's as plausible as that is only occurs with more complex functioning) in a snarky comment declaring the attempt pointless, rather than giving it as an actual "answer". It's a philosophy forum, who are you to declare any exploration of a key issue pointless in advance.

Comment: Wrong, it’s not a philosophy forum. It’s a philosophy Q&A site. Also voting to close, since there’s no unbiased answer to this question, a question that is seeking opinions and discussion.

Comment: As you can see from the [help center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help), this is not a forum and it is not for exploration. It is a Q&A and it is for questions already explored in the published literature. It is not that exploration is pointless but rather that discussions of users' speculations on this site are off-topic. So questions like yours are typically closed as opinion-based, they are too speculative to have literature on point and mostly invite opinions.

Comment: You're both oddly wrong and prejudiced. Simple to find e.g. a 2023 phil paper saying "Within the last 20 years, panpsychism has gained considerable attention, and today it is one of the most discussed views in philosophy of mind ... Despite all its merits, it is challenged by combination problems that need to be answered to make it plausible. I also do not rule out the possibility of other serious problems with it. However, Russellian panpsychism is still in its early stage of development and conceptual work needs to be undertaken to establish clearly what this view really is."

Comment: @Yop If you modify your question from being a statement of personal speculation into a question suitable for this site, I’ll retract my close vote. Name-calling is not persuasive.

Comment: Per connectionism the synaptic activation causing a neuron’s discrete all-or-none spike within its continuous chemical-electric field flows with axonal weight plasticity is a mark for the truth condition of a conscious quail. Beware continuity is a relative concept since the completion of quantum physics may be itself discrete. Ergo once any function unit produces complex distributed network of apparent plastic bivalence out of the underlying vast continuum or discrete set or lattice possibly with panpsychic sky views, consciousness may get chance to emerge, though still may not sufficiently …

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your question is on the way to being closed, so I will try to type a hasty answer before the shutters come down. Leaving aside the fact that you would have to elaborate what you envisage when you talk about small inanimate objects having qualia (the spellchecker changed that to quail, by the way, which is a bit annoying on a philosophy site) there are some common-sense objections that your idea would need to address before I, for one, would consider it plausible. For example, consciousness seems to be associated with processes in brains, rather than just being an innate property of a brain, like its mass. Moreover, the processes consume energy. Everything we suppose to have any sort of mind, such as humans, dogs, ants, elephants, consume food to provide energy to power their activity, a significant proportion of which is expended by the brain. Inanimate objects don't consume energy, and thus have no power source for consciousness. There are other common sense objections too- why would a brain deprived of free oxygen loose consciousness if the essential ingredients for consciousness were present in its constituent particles? Why would a brain seem to have only one consciousness? Why can't half of my brain co-join mentally with half of yours? Why is consciousness in my head, when the stuff from which it is made, namely atoms of carbon, hydrogen, oxygen, etc, also make up my feet? When panpsychism, or panqualism, is able to crush such objections in plain English, I will absolutely consider it plausible.

Comment: Ty for trying to use the site for its supposed purpose. My response is probably futile then but do you think the process point can be addressed by functionalism? That in some weird way (though intuitive to us on one level), qualia are the functions of a given entity. When the constituents are not working together functionally, I gather they still have their own energy in the electromagnetic flow in and around atoms, but I don't know if that has a function in the same sense.

Comment: @Yop -- these questions are highly relevant to any philosophy of mind speculation.  One of the problems for most speculations is that they would predict things should have minds that apparently do not.  For instance, we know that 99.9% of our brain functions are unconscious, and Functionalism predicts every one of these IS conscious, and necessarily so.  Why is a brain conscious, and not a toenail, or a toenail clipping, per pan-psychism?  Or our entire body?  First order falsified testable predictions from the basic theory make this implausible.

Comment: @Dcleve I think that's the key issue and I would've upvoted it as an answer. But I ask you, if the panpsychism is functionalist, it could reflect the overall functioning of a unit rather than each part any more? (a unit like "human ape" would have to have some ontological boundary). Alternatively, there could be consciousness within toenails, it's just that we're not toenails.

Comment: @Yop -- Panpsychism has no intrinsic coupling relationship between consciousness and any bundle object.  The only items that can coherently be claimed to be conscious would be elementary particles.    As consciousness is not causal in most versions of pan-psychism, there is no way to test for their claims of consciousness.  I am an interactive dualist -- one can apply empiricism to interactive dualism, it is a naturalist hypothesis.  Pan-psychism is not.  Answer upvote goes to Marco, who is NOT a dualist!!!!

Comment: I'm not a panpsychist, I'm a monist who's exploring possibilities about the as yet "hard problem" ie. intractable under current paradigm. I do not see that dualism can be naturalistically causal, unlike panpaychism. What you call bundles could be functional units, and perhaps the panpsychism is functionally elementary. But that would require ontological functions somehow. But functionalism is the mainstream consensus philosophy of mind. I'm not sure why last bitchy comment necessary, perhaps taking cue from other patronising jerk who likes talk down.